# Correct Sobolev Space for a Boundary Value Problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Given the two-point BVP:
\begin{align}
-(a(x)u'(x))'=f,\text{ in }(0,1)\\
u(0)=0\\
u'(1)=0
\end{align}

What is the appropriate Hilbert space for this problem. My idea is $H=H^2(0,1)\cap H_0^1[0,1]$. Is this correct?

Comment: Bernhard, does my answer sufficiently resolve your question? If not, can you let me know why? If yes, can you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=\{v\in H^1(0,1)\ |\ v(0)=0\}$. By multiplying the equation by some $v\in V$ and integrating on $(0,1)$, the problem becomes: find $u\in V$ such that
$$ \int_0^1 a u' v' = \int_0^1 f v \qquad \forall v\in V. $$
Suppose that $a(x)$ satisfies $a(x)\ge \alpha$ for all $x\in (0,1)$ and some $\alpha > 0$. Then the problem is well posed. Note that the Neumann BC is natural.